# is it possible to assign many assets within a single workflow?

Tags: workflow, liferay

I am developing a recruitment project using workflow by Liferay.
Assume that I have an organization with the following assets: CV, the first round test result, the second round test result; the third round test result.
And a recruitment workflow definition.
Is it possible to implement 4 assets within the workflow definition? And how to do it
thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more information? "Is it possible to implement 4 assets within the workflow definition?" is not very clear.

In liferay you can set one workflow definition to each asset (more assets can have the same definition). Is this what you want? Or do you want the assets somehow connected?

Comment: Hi Frant.
Thank for response :)
yes, I want the assets connected.
My workflow like this:
https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-Tm-7WYdPhTs/T6qC_BUDDkI/AAAAAAAAAPo/0ELW9jNXUjY/s512/14.JPG
and after each round, one more asset automatically be added
Hope you understand me :)
thank in advance!